# laravel custom pagination problem. the ?page=1 appending to base url not to current url

Tags: laravel, pagination

- the ?page=1 appending to base url not to current url
- css is not perfectly loading, I mean prev/next and page number buttons are not perfectly loading

  - the ?page=1 appending to base url not to current url
  - css is not perfectly loading, I mean prev/next and page number buttons are not perfectly loading

Comment: Your question does not make any sense. Please try and improve it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are going to use the Laravel custom pagination template. So run bellow command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

After running the above command, it will get new folder pagination on views files(resources/views/vendor/). And pagination folder by default following copy in \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pagination\resources\views the folder:

```
 resources\views\vendor\pagination\

bootstrap-4.blade.php
default.blade.php
semantic-ui.blade.php
simple-bootstrap-4.blade.php
simple-default.blade.php
simple-tailwind.blade.php
tailwind.blade.php
```

Then in your blade file add the following code:

```
  {{ $someVariable->links('vendor.pagination.custom') }}
```

I hope this will solve your problem.